# Check if div has opacity of 1 jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to check whether a slide has the opacity of 1 if it does i want to remove a class and then add a class, it works only on the first one currently this is my code .

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('#slide1').css('opacity') == 1) {
      alert("slide1");
      $('#slide1 img').removeClass("slider-in");
      $('#slide1 img').addClass("slider-come-in");
    }

    if ($('#slide2').css('opacity') == 1) {
      alert("slide2");
      $('#slide2 img').removeClass("slider-in");
      $('#slide2 img').addClass("slider-come-in");
    }

    if ($('#slide3').css('opacity') == 1) {
      alert("slide3");
      $('#slide3 img').removeClass("slider-in");
      $('#slide3 img').addClass("slider-come-in");
    }

    if ($('#slide4').css('opacity') == 1) {
      alert("slide4");
      $('#slide4 img').removeClass("slider-in");
      $('#slide4 img').addClass("slider-come-in");
    }

    if ($('#slide5').css('opacity') == 1) {
      alert("slide5");
      $('#slide5 img').removeClass("slider-in");
      $('#slide5 img').addClass("slider-come-in");
    }
  });
```

this is the jquery for the slider

```
   // Deal with the frontpage image

    if (fullPageImage.length > 0) {


        //Setup and start frontpage slideshow

        fullPageImage.css('background', 'none');        // Remove the fallback background;

        fullPageImage.children('.slide').each(function () { // Initialise each slide by setting its background image as the URI container in its data attributes

            var $this = $(this),
                bgImage = $this.attr('data-src');

            $this.css({'background-image' : 'url(' + bgImage + ')'});

        });

        fullPageImage.cycle(opts);

        $('.slide-next').click(function () {

            fullPageImage.cycle('next');

        });

        //Resize functions

        sizeBigImage();
        $(window).resize(function (e) {

            sizeBigImage();     // Resize slide container

        });
        window.onload = function() { sizeBigImage(); }

        // Scroll bind - For repositioning header and automated scrolls
        setTimeout(function () {positionHeader();}, 6000);

        $(window).scroll(function (e) {
            positionHeader();

            var newScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

            if (newScroll === 0) {
                fullPageImage.cycle('resume');
            } else {
                fullPageImage.cycle('pause');
            }


            lastScroll = newScroll;
        });



   Variable declaration / JQ element caching
    */
    var mainNav = $('#main_navigation'),
        mainHeader = $('#main_header'),
        $window = $(window),
        fullPageImage = $('#full_page_image'),
        opts = {
            timeout:            7000,       // how often the slides change
            speed:              750,        // how fast transitions occur
            fx:                 'fade',
            pause:              false,      // pause when use mouseovers page
            fit:                1,
            width:              '100%',
            height:             '100%',
            slideExpr:          '.slide',
            pager:              '.slider-pager',
            onPrevNextEvent: function(isNext, index, slideElement){
                       if ($(slideElement).css('opacity') == 1) {
                          $(slideElement).find('img').removeClass("slider-in");
                          $(slideElement).find('img').addClass("slider-come-in");
                      }
            },
            pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index, DOMElement) {

                return "<span class=\"icon-record slide-nav\"></span>";

            }
        },
        lastScroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
        menuButton = $('#menu_button'),
        downButton = $('#down_button');
```

Comment: Why don't you log the opacity and see if they're all right?

Comment: I think you are only checking on the DOM read event and not after each slide is updated

Comment: what does your HTML look like on pageload?

Comment: how would i go about checking when each slide is updated?

Comment: when page is loaded slide one is already loaded to it has the correct class but when the slide changes it doesnt change for the other slides

Comment: What are these slides, and how do you change them? We have no idea what you're talking about as "slides" can mean anything ?

Comment: you need to do this logic on `when slide changes` event.

Comment: What @PedroEstrada said, you need a slide change event. The reason your code only works on the first one is because it's the only one available when `$(document).ready` fires.

Comment: What are you using for your `slide` functionality? A custom built script or an already built slide plugin?

Comment: custom build just added the code

Comment: Are you using the [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin? And if so... is it the original version or cycle2? `fullPageImage.cycle('next');` is not a normal jquery command. `cycle` was added with a plugin.

Comment: its using cycle 1 sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the jQuery Cycle plugin (great plugin btw) you will probably want to add a slide change event like so:

```
$('#slider').cycle({
    after: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {
         $(currSlideElement).find('img').removeClass('slider-come-in');
         if ($(nextSlideElement).css('opacity') == 1) {
           $(nextSlideElement).find('img').removeClass("slider-in");
           $(nextSlideElement).find('img').addClass("slider-come-in");
      }
    },
    //Any other cycle options
});
```

[jQuery Cycle Options](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply i tryed that code but for some reason it just makes my slider really small

Comment: Could you share the code you use to intialize jquery cycle? Just add to your above post. Also, you can try and log your `sliderElement` in the above event and see what it's returning (I have added this in my above example).

Comment: When i click next console log shows the corrent div that is being displayed

Comment: its like its checking the opacity before the slide has actually been loaded

Comment: You may want to change the `onPrevNextEvent` with `after` which is an event that will fire after the slide transitions. I will update my code above with an example of how it looks.

Comment: its still only logging the slide when its got the opacity of 0

Comment: Updated the above code. I think `nextSlideElement` in the `after` event is what you want. It should have an opacity of 1

Comment: for some reason using the after is getting the slide before the current

Comment: ignore me its working now how would i remove the class when it goes to another slide?

Comment: I have updated this answer to remove the class of the old side before the transition. There is also a `before` event which may help you if you need some more control.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right,

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/L2T2V/

```
if($('div').css('opacity') == '1') {
    alert('Something!');
}
```

This will search for the css property of `opacity` and will create a condition of it.

What you might be facing, as you have said in comments

> how would i go about checking when each slide is updated?

Each time the script is executed, it looks for the current situation of the element, its current CSS and its current text! So, each time it would execute it would look for the current properties.

So it you're using or not using `opacity: 1` the script should execute, since the first and default value is `1` for `opacity`.

Comment: I don't think his problem is that he doesn't know who to check for `opacity`, but that he is doing it at the wrong time (just once on page load and not everytime a slide changes).

Comment: Yes, you're right! He knows perfectly how to check that, but he is confused what is the difference in checking the element at DOM ready and after that! His comment is qouted ..

Comment: hi guys i have added the code for the slider thanks for the help so far

Comment: @user41522, I still don't see any sort of change in `opacity` for the element. You're working it right, what is not working?

Comment: its using cycle 1 plugin but what i need it to do is everytime the slide changes i need to add a class to the images for that slide if the slide has the opacity of 1

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but if you add/remove classes anyway, why don't you just check if your slides have the class? feels like the easiest solution to me. Also, that way it'll still work, even if you, for example, create a different transition effect that doesn't manipulate the opacity (i.e. 'slide' instead of 'fade') later.